# Python : compare two list of strings in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to check if each word in the labels list exist in each list in the column 'bigrams'.

And if one these words exist in the bigram list, I would like to replace the label none by the word that exists.

I tried to write two consecutive for loop but it doesn't work. I also tried a comprehension list.

How can I do ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.Series.str.extract`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bgrams': [['hello','goodbye'],['dog','cat'],['cow']], 'label':[None,None,None]})
df
#             bgrams label
#0  [hello, goodbye]  None
#1        [dog, cat]  None
#2             [cow]  None

labels=['cat','goodbye']

regex='('+'|'.join(labels)+')'

df['label']=df.bgrams.astype(str).str.extract(regex)
```

Output:

```
df
             bgrams    label
0  [hello, goodbye]  goodbye
1        [dog, cat]      cat
2             [cow]      NaN
```

---

For multiple matches, you can use `pd.Series.str.findall`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bgrams': [['hello','goodbye','cat'],['dog','cat'],['cow']], 'label':[None,None,None]})
df
#             bgrams label
#0  [hello, goodbye, cat]  None
#1        [dog, cat]  None
#2             [cow]  None

labels=['cat','goodbye']

regex='('+'|'.join(labels)+')'

df['label']=df.bgrams.astype(str).str.findall(regex)
```

Output:

```
df
                  bgrams           label
0  [hello, goodbye, cat]  [goodbye, cat]
1             [dog, cat]           [cat]
2                  [cow]              []
```

Comment: You're welcome @LJRB, if it works for you, consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235), thanks :)

Comment: It works but not for all the words I have in the list. When I create the variable regex the new list inverted some words. For example if I have 'guerre virus' it inverted the two words. So maybe it will not find 'guerre virus'. I would like to find both 'guerre virus' or 'virus guerre'.